# I can´t write the data of the vector table to the textfile, but the program runs without trouble

Tags: java, vector, fileoutputstream

The program runs smooth and i can see the values of the vector in the editor, but i can´t see the values in the text file

```
FileManagement FileManagement = new FileManagement();
            String sti = "D:\\El teknik/Data.txt";
        /*En Vector er en liste af andre objekter, men den kan betragtes som en tabel
        ligesom et array. Fordelen ved en Vector er, at ikke angives en bestemt længde 
        i tabellen*/
            Vector dataTabel = new Vector();
        // konstruktør til at initialisere objektet
```

These 3 lines are the values i want inside the textfile

```
 Data dataoplysning1 = new Data("Hjemmeside","brugernavn","password");
/*Jeg kalder min vektor personTabel og gemmer oplysninger i vector´en og vector
Vector klassen har en metode add(objekt), der tilføjer et objekt sidst i vektoren
*/  dataTabel.add(dataoplysning1);/*dette er et menupunkt, som opretter et objekt
og gemmer i vector´en*/
    Data dataoplysning2 = new Data("Facebook.com", "Bjarne Olsen", "The1bad32feel");
    dataTabel.add(dataoplysning2);
    Data dataoplysning3= new Data("Twitter", "Herman Jessen","Degode3fort3l");
    dataTabel.add(dataoplysning3);
```

i call the static method down below

```
//jeg kalder den static-metode save(Vector v, String sti)
    FileManagement.save(dataTabel,sti);
//det kan være et nyt menupunkt, som gemmer vector´en på harddisken
    Vector nyDataTabel = new Vector();
    nyDataTabel=FileManagement.load(nyDataTabel,sti);
/* Henter tabellen på harddisken, som ikke bør være et menupunkt, men filen hentes
på harddisken, når programmet starter*/
for (int idx=0;idx<nyDataTabel.size();idx++)
{
    dataoplysning1=(Data)nyDataTabel.elementAt(idx);
    System.out.println("Hjemmeside. :"+dataoplysning1.getHjemmeside());
    System.out.println("Brugernavn. :"+dataoplysning1.getusername());
    System.out.println("Password. :"+dataoplysning1.getpassword());
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
}
//Et menupunkt som udskriver hele vector´en
for (int idx=0;idx<nyDataTabel.size();idx++)
{
    dataoplysning2 = (Data)nyDataTabel.elementAt(idx);
    String Hjemmeside = dataoplysning2.getHjemmeside();
    if (Hjemmeside.compareTo("Facebook.com")==0)
    {
        System.out.println("Find følgende brugernavn og password");
        System.out.println("Hjemmeside. :"+dataoplysning2.getHjemmeside());
        System.out.println("Brugernavn. :"+dataoplysning2.getusername());
        System.out.println("Password. :"+dataoplysning2.getpassword());
        idx=nyDataTabel.size();
    }/*Det er et menupunkt, der søger efter brugeroplysninger på en bestem 
hjemmeside i vector´en*/
else {
        System.out.println("Dataerne passer ikke med hinanden");
     }
}    
//    AES_encryption.user();//kalder metoden 
    AES_encryption.skriv(sti, x);
    }
```

The method below is where it writes the vector values out to the text file, which is where the problem is

```
public static void skriv(String fileName, Vector dataTabel) throws IOException 
    {
        BufferedWriter outputWriter=null;
        outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
    for (int i = 0;i <dataTabel.size();i++)
    {
    //skriver enten 
    outputWriter.write(dataTabel.get(i) + "");
    // eller 

    outputWriter.write(Integer.toString((int) dataTabel.get(i)));//her gemmer den arrayet til tekststrengen
    outputWriter.newLine();//den går videre til en ny linje
    }
    outputWriter.flush(); //gemmer arrayet til tekstrengen filnavn
    outputWriter.close();//afslutter gemning af fil og metoden
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although without entire codes I cannot run your codes in my site, I guess FileManagement.save() seems to call skriv() to save the table. So I'd like suggest what you may try with method skriv();

The first write() in skriv() gets datatabel.get(i) for writting, but the type of each elements of datatabel is an Object, not a value, thus I suggest to use Object serialization rather than BufferedReader. Or you may separate fields into strings, which results in three file writtings (or one writting of a concatenated string of three strings) per each i.

Comment: Well i found the solution later on, it was almost like u said because of object serialization, which i forgot to add and then i deleted the other method containing BufferedReader.